# How to get supported extensions in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm working on a C++ application that uses Vulkan. How do I get the set of supported extensions?

A signature like `std::set<std::string> get_supported_extensions()` would be ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties.html) API does this.

```cpp
std::set<std::string> get_supported_extensions() {
    VkResult result = 0;

    /*
     * From the link above:
     * If `pProperties` is NULL, then the number of extensions properties
     * available is returned in `pPropertyCount`.
     *
     * Basically, gets the number of extensions.
     */
    uint32_t count = 0;
    result = vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &count, nullptr);
    if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        // Throw an exception or log the error
    }

    std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> extensionProperties(count);

    // Get the extensions
    result = vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &count, extensionProperties.data());
    if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        // Throw an exception or log the error
    }

    std::set<std::string> extensions;
    for (auto & extension : extensionProperties) {
        extensions.insert(extension.extensionName);
    }

    return extensions;
}
```

Comment: For the example to be complete you should perform `VkResult` checks (`ERROR` to C++ exception might be a good fit). Might not hurt anything to perform `do{ ... }while(VK_INCOMPLETE)` ;; Vulkan-Hpp is always an option too